# Selecting and moving imported SVG files in D3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I’m experimenting with d3 and I’ve been trying to work with simple svg images that I’ve made with Illustrator.

I can append the submarine.svg image to my working document, but I have trouble selecting it and adjusting it’s position.

I’m aware that I can do this another way, but I would like to learn more about d3.

Here is my attempt at placing the svg at 500px across the x axis.

```
var submarine = d3.xml("submarine.svg", "image/svg+xml", function(xml) { document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement)
      }) d3.select(this).attr("x","500");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/y1ye2u8s/2/

```
// Define a drag behavior for the image.
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag", dragmove);

// Function that is called upong dragging.
function dragmove(d) {

      var x = d3.event.x;
      var y = d3.event.y;

      // Select and move the image upon dragging.
      d3.select(this)
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + (x-200) + "," + (y-200) + ")");
}

d3.xml("https://rawgit.com/VengadoraVG/moving-to-gnulinux/master/img/tux.svg", "image/svg+xml", 

    function (xml) {

        // Add the image to the document.
        document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);

        // Select the svg element representing the image.
        d3.select("svg")

            // Set the svg viewport dimensions.
            .attr("width", "1000")
            .attr("height", "1000");

       // Apply the drag behavior to the image.
       d3.select("svg").select("g")
            .call(drag);    

});
```